# Why do different update results occur for equally synchronized users?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have the Azure AD users that are synced from my on-premises AD.
When I updated the user's properties (such as displayName, department, and so on), some users succeeded in updating, but some users failed to update.

In Azure AD, the audit logs of the update successful user and the failed user are as follows.

```
////////////////// update success user
{
"id": "Directory_xxxxxxx_112926480",
"category": "UserManagement",
"correlationId": "xxxxx",
"result": "success",
"resultReason": "",
"activityDisplayName": "Update user",
"activityDateTime": "2022-02-07T07:03:44.6467812Z",
"loggedByService": "Core Directory",
"operationType": "Update",
"initiatedBy": {
"user": null,
"app": {
"appId": null,
"displayName": "xxxx",
"servicePrincipalId": "xxxx",
"servicePrincipalName": null
}
},
"targetResources": [
{
"id": "xxxx",
"displayName": null,
"type": "User",
"userPrincipalName": "xxxx@xxxx",
"groupType": null,
"modifiedProperties": [
{
"displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
"oldValue": null,
"newValue": "\"\""
},
{
"displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
"oldValue": null,
"newValue": "\"Member\""
}
]
}
],
"additionalDetails": [
{
"key": "UserType",
"value": "Member"
},
{
"key": "User-Agent",
"value": "Apache CXF 3.2.14"
}
]
},


////////////////// update fail user
{
"id": "Directory_xxxx_118537500",
"category": "UserManagement",
"correlationId": "xxxx",
"result": "failure",
"resultReason": "Microsoft.Online.Workflows.PropertyUpdateNotAllowedException",
"activityDisplayName": "Update user",
"activityDateTime": "2022-02-07T07:03:04.9716261Z",
"loggedByService": "Core Directory",
"operationType": "Update",
"initiatedBy": {
"user": null,
"app": {
"appId": null,
"displayName": "xxxx",
"servicePrincipalId": "xxxx",
"servicePrincipalName": null
}
},
"targetResources": [
{
"id": "xxxx",
"displayName": null,
"type": "User",
"userPrincipalName": "xxxx@xxx",
"groupType": null,
"modifiedProperties": [
{
"displayName": "MethodExecutionResult.",
"oldValue": null,
"newValue": "\"Microsoft.Online.Workflows.PropertyUpdateNotAllowedException\""
},
{
"displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
"oldValue": null,
"newValue": "\"Member\""
}
]
}
],
"additionalDetails": [
{
"key": "UserType",
"value": "Member"
},
{
"key": "User-Agent",
"value": "Apache CXF 3.2.14"
}
]
},
```

Could you tell why the results are so different?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some user details are failed to update because of the error:

`Microsoft.Online.Workflows.PropertyUpdateNotAllowedException`

***The above error usually occurs for many reasons like:***

- There may be some attributes that **violate formatting requirements** which restrict characters and character length of attribute values.
- The attributes that require unique values may have **duplicate attribute values** in existing user account (on-prem AD).
- May be the **user principal name (UPN)** was changed after the initial synchronization and must be updated manually.
- Some attributes may match **exclusion rules** for directory synchronization.
- The **domain value** that's used by AD DS attributes hasn't been verified.

***To resolve this error, please check the below workarounds if they are helpful:***

- Use the [IdFix DirSync Error Remediation Tool](https://github.com/microsoft/idfix) to check for duplicates, missing attributes, and rule violations.
- **Update AD DS attributes** to remove duplicates, rule violations, and scoping exclusions.
- Make sure the user properties can’t contain **accent characters** and the size of displayName, department etc… are under the maximum limits.

For more information in detail, go through below references.

**References:**

[One or more objects don't sync when the Azure Active Directory Sync tool is used - Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/objects-dont-sync-ad-sync-tool)

[Troubleshoot directory synchronization errors with event 6941 - Office 365 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/active-directory/duplicate-attributes-prevent-dirsync)